# Using Broadcast receiver inside of a parse query

Tags: android, parse-platform, broadcastreceiver, android-recyclerview, countdowntimer

I have a BroadcastService class which broadcasts the contents of a CountDownTimer to my RecyclerView. I can't figure out how to receive this broadcast from the inside of a Parse query.

I'm able to receive the broadcast if my receiver is outside of the done query, but when I put it inside I receive nothing. How can I receive the contents of the timer and then proceed to add it to my adapter? Btw-- the service broadcasts each new second via the onTick() method of the CountDownTimer.

```
import android.app.Service;
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.IntentFilter;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.os.CountDownTimer;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.parse.FindCallback;
import com.parse.ParseException;
import com.parse.ParseObject;
import com.parse.ParseQuery;
import com.parse.ParseUser;

import java.io.DataOutputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;


public class MainActivity extends  ActionBarActivity implements DataAdapter.ClickListener {
    private RecyclerView recyclerView;
    static DataAdapter adapter;

    public TextView tvParseUser;
    private Context context;
    String currentUser;

    Data current;

    List<Data> data = new ArrayList<>();

    public static String BROADCAST_ACTION =
            "package_name.countdown_br";



    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        context = this;
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter();
        filter.addAction(BROADCAST_ACTION);
        filter.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_DEFAULT);
        registerReceiver(br, filter);

        adapter = new DataAdapter(this, data);

        startService(new Intent(this, Broadcast_Service.class));
        tvParseUser = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.ParseUserName);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = ParseQuery.getQuery("QuerySubject");
        query.whereEqualTo("author", ParseUser.getCurrentUser());
        recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recyclerView); 
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));

        query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseObject>() {

            @Override
            public void done(List<ParseObject> list, ParseException e) { 
                if (e == null)
                {
                    for (ParseObject getData : list)
                    {

                        Data current = new Data();

                        BroadcastReceiver br = new BroadcastReceiver() {
                            @Override
                            public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
                                if (intent.getExtras() != null)
                                {
                                    long millisUntilFinished = intent.getLongExtra("countdown", 0);

                                    current.Timer = String.valueOf(intent.getExtras().getLong("countdown") / 1000);
                                }                                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                            }
                        };

                        current.1 = getData.getString("1");
                        current.2= getData.getString("2");
                        current.3= getData.getString("3");
                        current.4= getData.getString("4");
                        current.5= getData.getString("5");

                        current.combined= current.1+ " for " + current.2+ " " + current.3+ " per " + current.4;

                        adapter.addData(current);
                        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    }
                }
            }
        });
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume()
    {
        super.onResume();
        registerReceiver(br, new IntentFilter(Broadcast_Service.COUNTDOWN_BR));
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        unregisterReceiver(br);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1. You should consider using LocalBroadcastReceiver if the broadcast receiver is just local to your app.
2. You haven't declared your broadcast receiver yet but you are already registering it. That means you are problably registering a null value.
3. You should move the registration of the broadcast receiver inside the done too. (This is under the assumption that you only want to listen to broadcasts only after a successful query). **EDIT** Actually I think this is a bad design since you are creating a broadcast receiver in a loop. Ideally you should only have one broadcast receiver.
4. Be sure to unregister your broadcastreceiver before exiting this activity.